# Using select2 gem in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-select2

I'm trying to integrate the select2 gem into my app to make my selects use jquery and look better.  I've installed the gem and added the appropriate lines to my assets, but I'm not sure how to call it on a select.

Here's an example of my select without it.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to call select2 on this to get it working?

Comment: Here is a gist of what I'm trying to do, even when declaring the JS I still can't get the collection_select to use select2

Answer (score 4):

The select2-rails gem only gives you an easy way to include the Select2 assets, but it does not include any rails helper to call it.

In other words, you have to call it on your own from your javascript.

For instance ,in application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').select2();
});
```

This would call select2 over every select in your app.

Hope it helps.

Comment: For some reason, this creates duplicate labels and input fields for me. It also doesn't style correctly as shown in the examples of select2.